# Phalcon - multiple checkboxes in forms

Tags: php, phalcon

Basically, I need to serialize multiple checkboxes before saving them in database and unserialize before displaying the form.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="list[option1]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="list[option2]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="list[option3]" value="1">
```

Could someone point me to the right direction please?

I've tried the following code to generate the checkboxes, but it's not working after the request. 
Selected options are not getting populated to the form (other fields are fine)

```
<?php
$form->bind($_POST, $entity);
....
foreach ($list as $key => $option) {
  $form->add(new Check("list[$key]", array('value' => 1)));
}
```

I suppose the same issue exists with using multi-choice select boxes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a typo. Try:

```
<?php
$form->bind($_POST, $entity);
....
foreach ($list as $key => $option) {
  $form->add(new Check($list[$key], array('value' => 1)));
}
```

On a side note, the [Phalcon\Tag](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Tag.html) helper can be used to generate HTML.

```
<?php

echo Phalcon\Tag::checkField(array($list[$key], "value" => "1"));
```

Comment: It isn't a typo. I intentionally need to send the selected checkboxes as POST array

Answer (score 0):

You can using my code Fdola.com.
Use

```
<?php 
$list_module = new \App\Vendor\Fdola\Forms\CheckBoxList('list_module', ['a' => 'A', 'b' => 'B'], ['a'], ['class' => 'checkBoxList']);
$list_module->setLabel('Module hiển thị banner:');
$list_module->addValidators([
    new \Phalcon\Validation\Validator\PresenceOf([
        'message' => '<b>:field</b> không được phép rỗng'
    ])
]);
$this->add($list_module);
```

---

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: thanhansoft
 * Date: 4/29/2016
 * Time: 4:21 PM
 */

namespace App\Vendor\Fdola\Forms;

use Phalcon\Http\Request;
use Phalcon\Tag;

class CheckBoxList extends \Phalcon\Forms\Element {
    private $_data;
    private $_dataOld;

    public function __construct($name, $data, $dataOld = null, $attribute = null) {
        $this->_data = $data;
        $this->_dataOld = $dataOld;
        parent::__construct($name, $attribute);
    }

    public function render($attribute = null) {
        $get_value = $this->getValue();
        if ($get_value) {
            $data = $get_value;
        } else {
            $data = $this->_dataOld;
        }

        $tag = new Tag();
        $string = '';
        if ($this->_data) {
            foreach ($this->_data as $key => $value) {
                $arr = ['id' => $this->_name . '-' . $key, 'name' => $this->_name . '[]', 'value' => $key];

                if ($data && in_array($key, $data)) {
                    $arr['checked'] = 'checked';
                }

                $string .= '<label>' . $tag::checkField($arr) . ' ' . $value . '</label>';
            }
        }

        if (isset($this->_attributes['class'])) return '<div class="' . $this->_attributes['class'] . '">' . $string . '</div>';
        return $string;
    }
}
```